# How to shade in recesses in a glass shader with Eevee?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, glass

I am attempting to create a frosted glass shader similar to the art below. I would primarily like to do this in Eevee with the potential of seamlessly switching between Cycles and Eevee. I know that this affect would be possible with the pointiness input in Cycles but is there a better way to approach this?

While I would like the shader to have some transmission it is not a must have.

[image: A turnaround of the Peeping Tom vigor from Bioshock Infinite]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tho this solutuion kinda looks good in eeve, the result is not the same in both render engines

**Solution 1:** (if background if a flat color)
[image]

**Solution 2:** (less shiny: dimmed with flat color bg; no super reflections with hdri)
[image]

**Solution 3: ** (super reflections are there but you can tweak their `opacity` with `To Max` value in newly added `map range` node at the bottom
you can also play around with other `map range` node values, it manipulates amount of super reflections
[image]

**Solution 4:** (balanced super reflections (for me it's the best)
here you can tweak same values of `map range` node, as well as bright/contrast, `value` in `hue saturation value` node, `roughness` and `IOR` in `Refraction BSDF` node
[image]

For different hdri, different solutions will work better, pls test.
In addition, here is the .blend file with all the materials:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot this works really well with a flat colour background but with an HDRI it is hyper reflective. I can adjust it somewhat by changing the Contrast value of the Bright Contrast Node but that limits the reflective areas.

Comment: i'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!